# Type mismatch with If statement containing bitwise operators

Tags: scala, types, bitwise-operators, type-mismatch

I am new to scala but I am having the problem with the following code:

```
var c:Int = 0
var j:Int = 0

for( c <- 0 to 100){
  for( j <- 0 to 100){

   /* Check if jth bit in c is set,
    if( (c & (1<<j)) )  // this line is the line where i get the error
    xs :+ (ys(j))   // this is copying element j from list ys to list xs     
  }
}
```

The error I get is:
type mismatch;  found   : Int  required: Boolean

the code  `(c & (1<<j))`  should be shifting 1 left j bits and then bitwise anding the result to the int in the variable c to get a boolean result.

It is entirely possible that I am doing something wrong.. I have been learning Scala fro 3 days and I am very rusty on my java.

Any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operations in Scala (in fact in any language) return a result of type `Int`, your if expression requires a type of `Boolean`. Scala doesn't treat `Boolean` values like C, where you code would work fine.

You can make your expression return a `Boolean` by testing explicitly for `1`:

```
if((c & (1 << j)) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in C (or C++), Scala's `if` statement (just like Java) only accepts a `Boolean` expression, and there is no implicit type promotion from integral types to `Boolean`. So you need to be explicit about what you want, and replace `if( (c & (1<<j)) )` with `if( (c & (1<<j)) != 0)`